# How does a Geiger counter, such as RD1706, converts counts per minute to micro Sievert per hour?

Tags: measurements, radioactivity

The [RADEX RD1706](https://www.quarta-rad.ru/en/catalog/dozimetr-radiometr-radon/dozimetr-radex-rd1706/) contains two SBM20-1 type Geiger–Müller counters.

I understand how the counts per minute value can be computed. But how is the micro Sievert per hour value obtained? And what is its meaning?

Comment: Does [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert) answer your question? If so, I can compose an answer.

Comment: Yes, if you can summarize [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert) into an answer to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/272649/how-does-a-geiger-counter-such-as-rd1706-converts-counts-per-minute-to-micro-s), it would be very helpful.

Comment: A Geiger counter is a very crude instrument---mostly useful in surveying an area for radioactive contamination.  I would not expect anybody to use one in a scientific experiment unless (a) the budget was tight, and (b) the counter could be calibrated to account for the type and energies of the expected particles.  (That, incidentally, is the answer to your question:  The counts/minute measurement is multiplied by a calibration factor that assumes a particular mix of particle types and energies.)

Comment: Unrelated question but [possibly useful answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/68872/) (see the digression on units).

Answer (score 2):

The [sievert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert) (Sv) is a derived unit of ionizing radiation dose in the international system of units. It is a measure of the health effect of low levels of radiation on the body. For radiation dose assessment, it shows the probability of cancer and DNA damage. One sievert carries with it a 5.5% chance of developing cancer. One sievert = 100 [rem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roentgen_equivalent_man). Two commonly used prefixes are the millisievert and the microsievert (1 μSv = 0.000001 Sv). Frequently used units for dose rate indications on instruments are μSv/h (microsieverts per hour).

The definition of the sievert given by the [International Committee for Weights and Measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Committee_for_Weights_and_Measures) is $H = Q \times D$, where $H$ is the quantity dose equivalent, $D$ is the absorbed dose of ionizing radiation and $Q$ is the dimensionless quality factor defined as a function of linear energy transfer. The unit for the sievert is joule per kilogram according to the [ICRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Commission_on_Radiological_Protection).

For the counter itself, it is calibrated to the proper value using radiation metrology techniques which trace the values to a national standard and then relate them to an operational quantity. Another method of calibrating can be done via the radiation type weighting factor described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert#Radiation_type_weighting_factor_WR).

Hope this helps!

**Note:**

Considering your comment asking how to convert sieverts per minute to microsieverts per hour, I created an example calculation.

If your value is 1 sievert/minute (which is a really high value; I'm just using this number for roundness):

$$1 \frac {Sv}{min} * \frac {60 min}{1 hour} * \frac {10^6 \mu Sv}{1 Sv} = \frac {1*60*10^6}{1*1*1} \frac {Sv * min * \mu Sv}{min * hour * Sv} = 60,000,000 \frac {\mu Sv}{hour}$$

**Note 2:**

In the case of your updated question in the comments, technically there isn't *really* a direct equation converting counts per minute (CPM) to microsieverts because CPM is an electron count and microsieverts is a count of bodily damage.

Comment: Thank you for your summary. Can you develop on the relation between the counts per hour value and the microsievert per hour value? Is it linear?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni, does my update answer your question?

Comment: What I'm looking for, is a mathematical relation between the counts per minute value and the microsievert per hour value.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni, does my new update help, or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: You misundertood my question. I was asking about the relation between [counts per minute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counts_per_minute) and microsievert per hour.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni, I updated my answer to address that. My apologies for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion between CPM and uSv/h is done via a conversion factor. According to this [site](https://sites.google.com/site/geigerbot/tech-info):

> Conversion factor is usually calibrated to gamma activity from
>   a Co-60 or Cs-137 source.  It is specific to your tube, the
>   radioisotope, and type of radiation.  It is usually given only for
>   gamma radiation.  (actual gamma sensitivity is something like 1-10%
>   depending on the isotope)

For a given tube, there is no consensus on which value to use. You can find here a [list](https://sapporohibaku.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/conversion-factor/) of different values used by different people.